# Getting type error from require function of module.exports in nodejs firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that I am exporting and importing inside another file. Now this export function is used in a lot of place inside the application and it's working fine everywhere else but for some reason it's becoming undefined inside the cloud function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();
const {
  checkAndGetApplicationMode,
} = require("../Utils/application-setup-functions");

exports.createCause = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log("applicationMode check", checkAndGetApplicationMode); // Undefined
  console.log("applicationMode check", checkAndGetApplicationMode()); // TypeError: checkAndGetApplicationMode is not a function
});
```

Although If I hover over it in my vs code it does give me reference to the actual function.
[image]

Here is the file structure for more information. I am using this `checkAndGetApplicationMode` function in many other files and it's working fine there. Also if I try require inside the function then works but if i require it outside the file then it gives `undefined`

File Stucture

[image]

Comment: Can you show your folders structure? In particular to see where are the `Utils` and `functions` folders relatively to each other.

Comment: If `require` ends up returning an empty object, it normally indicates that you have a recursive loop of require instructions (if you are 100% sure it's not a typo). Make sure you aren't calling something like `require('B.js')` in `A.js`, where `B.js` is also calling `require('A.js')`. It's possible that this will only appear with two particular files and no others which can make tracking it down tricky. You may also want to consider breaking out `require('firebase-admin')` into its own `./firebase-admin.js` file where `initializeApp` is called.